# Kafka Topic Delete And Recreation Problem

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I need to delete some topics in my project at any time.

I was able to achieve this using AdminClient. However, sometimes I have a problem. Let's say I want to delete topic "xtopic". Kafka is really deleting this topic. Then I create it again programmatically. I also see that topic has been created.

Even though I send no deletion request again, the relevant topic is deleted within a few seconds. Even if I create the topic over and over again, I experience the same situation. I manage to create the topic, but kafka deletes the topic within a few seconds.. If I want to delete 1000 topics, this happens 1 time. I couldn't understand the situation. Why might such a problem occur?

- Kafka Server: cp-kafka:5.3.0-jmx-prometheus
- Cluster: 6 Kafka Servers
- Microservices: 70 Microservices
- Kafka Client Version: 2.6.3
- auto.create.topic : false

Topic Configuration :

```
default-configuration:
  kafka:
    replication-factor: 6
    partition-count: 8
    min-insync-replicas: 3
    retention-ms: 300000000
    segment-bytes: 300000000
```

Delete Topic Code :

```
private void deleteTopics(AdminClient adminClient, Collection<String> topicNameCollection) {
    this.getRetryTemplate().execute((retryContext) -> {
        Set<String> allTopicSet = adminClient.listTopics().names().get(this.defaultProperties.getKafkaFutureTimeoutMs(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        List<String> existingTopics = topicNameCollection.stream().filter(allTopicSet::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (!existingTopics.isEmpty()) {
            DeleteTopicsResult deleteTopicsResult = adminClient.deleteTopics(topicNameCollection);
            try {
                deleteTopicsResult.all().get(this.defaultProperties.getKafkaFutureTimeoutMs(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (Exception var6) {
                throw new CannotDeleteTopicException("An error occurred while deleting topic.", var6);
            }
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

Kafka Server Log :

```
[2023-11-25 14:09:21,396] INFO [Controller id=3] New partition creation callback for example-topic-live-321-0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,397] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed partition example-topic-live-321-0 state from NonExistentPartition to NewPartition with assigned replicas 3 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,397] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed state of replica 3 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 from NonExistentReplica to NewReplica (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,422] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed partition example-topic-live-321-0 from NewPartition to OnlinePartition with state LeaderAndIsr(leader=3, leaderEpoch=0, isr=List(3), zkVersion=0) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,422] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Sending become-leader LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=1, leader=3, leaderEpoch=0, isr=3, zkVersion=0, replicas=3, isNew=true) to broker 3 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,422] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Sending UpdateMetadata request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=1, leader=3, leaderEpoch=0, isr=[3], zkVersion=0, replicas=[3], offlineReplicas=[]) to brokers Set(1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4) for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,422] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed state of replica 3 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 from NewReplica to OnlineReplica (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,428] TRACE [Broker id=3] Received LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=1, leader=3, leaderEpoch=0, isr=3, zkVersion=0, replicas=3, isNew=true) correlation id 3415 from controller 3 epoch 1 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,428] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3410 sent to broker b2d4aa4caa56:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,429] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3413 sent to broker 229e7f8f9aa3:9092 (id: 2 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,429] TRACE [Broker id=3] Handling LeaderAndIsr request correlationId 3415 from controller 3 epoch 1 starting the become-leader transition for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,429] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 3] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(example-topic-live-321-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)


[2023-11-25 14:09:21,431] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3407 sent to broker 9ad81f65aff3:9092 (id: 5 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,433] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3415 sent to broker 55b8913446d5:9092 (id: 6 rack: null) (state.change.logger)


[2023-11-25 14:09:21,436] INFO [Log partition=example-topic-live-321-0, dir=/var/lib/kafka/data] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,437] INFO [Log partition=example-topic-live-321-0, dir=/var/lib/kafka/data] Completed load of log with 1 segments, log start offset 0 and log end offset 0 in 2 ms (kafka.log.Log)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,437] INFO Created log for partition example-topic-live-321-0 in /var/lib/kafka/data with properties {compression.type -> producer, message.downconversion.enable -> true, min.insync.replicas -> 1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, cleanup.policy -> [delete], flush.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.bytes -> 1073741824, retention.ms -> 604800000, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807, message.format.version -> 2.3-IV1, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, max.compaction.lag.ms -> 9223372036854775807, max.message.bytes -> 20971520, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, preallocate -> false, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, unclean.leader.election.enable -> false, retention.bytes -> -1, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, segment.ms -> 604800000, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760}. (kafka.log.LogManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,439] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3413 sent to broker a812096936e6:9092 (id: 4 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,469] INFO [Partition example-topic-live-321-0 broker=3] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,469] INFO Replica loaded for partition example-topic-live-321-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,469] INFO [Partition example-topic-live-321-0 broker=3] example-topic-live-321-0 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,473] TRACE [Broker id=3] Stopped fetchers as part of become-leader request from controller 3 epoch 1 with correlation id 3415 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (last update controller epoch 1) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,473] TRACE [Broker id=3] Completed LeaderAndIsr request correlationId 3415 from controller 3 epoch 1 for the become-leader transition for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,474] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0,partitions=[{topic=example-topic-live-321,partition=0,error_code=0}]} for request LEADER_AND_ISR with correlation id 3415 sent to broker 62ecda170292:9092 (id: 3 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,475] TRACE [Broker id=3] Cached leader info PartitionState(controllerEpoch=1, leader=3, leaderEpoch=0, isr=[3], zkVersion=0, replicas=[3], offlineReplicas=[]) for partition example-topic-live-321-0 in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 3 epoch 1 with correlation id 3416 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:21,476] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3416 sent to broker 62ecda170292:9092 (id: 3 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,613] DEBUG [Controller id=3] Delete topics listener fired for topics example-topic-live-321 to be deleted (kafka.controller.KafkaController)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,613] INFO [Controller id=3] Starting topic deletion for topics example-topic-live-321 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,613] INFO [Topic Deletion Manager 3] Handling deletion for topics example-topic-live-321 (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,613] INFO [Topic Deletion Manager 3] Deletion of topic example-topic-live-321 (re)started (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,613] INFO [Topic Deletion Manager 3] Topic deletion callback for example-topic-live-321 (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,613] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed partition example-topic-live-321-0 state from OnlinePartition to OfflinePartition (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,613] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed partition example-topic-live-321-0 state from OfflinePartition to NonExistentPartition (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,614] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Sending UpdateMetadata request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=1, leader=-2, leaderEpoch=0, isr=[3], zkVersion=0, replicas=[3], offlineReplicas=[]) to brokers Set(1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4) for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,614] INFO [Topic Deletion Manager 3] Partition deletion callback for example-topic-live-321-0 (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,617] TRACE [Broker id=3] Deleted partition example-topic-live-321-0 from metadata cache in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 3 epoch 1 with correlation id 3417 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,618] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Removed 0 offsets associated with deleted partitions: example-topic-live-321-0. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,619] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3411 sent to broker b2d4aa4caa56:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,621] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3417 sent to broker 62ecda170292:9092 (id: 3 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,623] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3408 sent to broker 9ad81f65aff3:9092 (id: 5 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,624] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3414 sent to broker a812096936e6:9092 (id: 4 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,624] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3414 sent to broker 229e7f8f9aa3:9092 (id: 2 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,631] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0} for request UPDATE_METADATA with correlation id 3416 sent to broker 55b8913446d5:9092 (id: 6 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,743] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed state of replica 3 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 from OnlineReplica to OfflineReplica (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,743] DEBUG The stop replica request (delete = false) sent to broker 3 is StopReplicaRequestInfo([Topic=example-topic-live-321,Partition=0,Replica=3],false) (kafka.controller.ControllerBrokerRequestBatch)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,743] DEBUG [Topic Deletion Manager 3] Deletion started for replicas [Topic=example-topic-live-321,Partition=0,Replica=3] (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,743] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed state of replica 3 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 from OfflineReplica to ReplicaDeletionStarted (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,744] DEBUG The stop replica request (delete = true) sent to broker 3 is StopReplicaRequestInfo([Topic=example-topic-live-321,Partition=0,Replica=3],true) (kafka.controller.ControllerBrokerRequestBatch)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,748] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 3] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(example-topic-live-321-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,748] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 3] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(example-topic-live-321-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,749] TRACE [Broker id=3] Handling stop replica (delete=false) for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,749] TRACE [Broker id=3] Finished handling stop replica (delete=false) for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,751] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0,partitions=[{topic=example-topic-live-321,partition=0,error_code=0}]} for request STOP_REPLICA with correlation id 3418 sent to broker 62ecda170292:9092 (id: 3 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,752] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 3] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(example-topic-live-321-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,752] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 3] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(example-topic-live-321-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,752] TRACE [Broker id=3] Handling stop replica (delete=true) for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,757] INFO The cleaning for partition example-topic-live-321-0 is aborted and paused (kafka.log.LogCleaner)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,757] INFO The cleaning for partition example-topic-live-321-0 is aborted (kafka.log.LogCleaner)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,863] INFO Log for partition example-topic-live-321-0 is renamed to /var/lib/kafka/data/example-topic-live-321-0.68e5c26ab83a4b8ba3424ef5178ff1ca-delete and is scheduled for deletion (kafka.log.LogManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,863] TRACE [Broker id=3] Finished handling stop replica (delete=true) for partition example-topic-live-321-0 (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,864] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Received response {error_code=0,partitions=[{topic=example-topic-live-321,partition=0,error_code=0}]} for request STOP_REPLICA with correlation id 3419 sent to broker 62ecda170292:9092 (id: 3 rack: null) (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,864] DEBUG [Controller id=3] Delete topic callback invoked on StopReplica response received from broker 3: request error = NONE, partition errors = Map(example-topic-live-321-0 -> NONE) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,864] DEBUG [Topic Deletion Manager 3] Deletion successfully completed for replicas [Topic=example-topic-live-321,Partition=0,Replica=3] (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,864] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed state of replica 3 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 from ReplicaDeletionStarted to ReplicaDeletionSuccessful (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,864] INFO [Topic Deletion Manager 3] Handling deletion for topics example-topic-live-321 (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,864] TRACE [Controller id=3 epoch=1] Changed state of replica 3 for partition example-topic-live-321-0 from ReplicaDeletionSuccessful to NonExistentReplica (state.change.logger)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,897] INFO [Topic Deletion Manager 3] Deletion of topic example-topic-live-321 successfully completed (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,938] INFO [Controller id=3] New topics: [Set()], deleted topics: [Set()], new partition replica assignment [Map()] (kafka.controller.KafkaController)

[2023-11-25 14:09:25,964] DEBUG [Controller id=3] Delete topics listener fired for topics  to be deleted (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "this happens 1 time". What's "this"? Note that you're not actually checking the result from `deleteTopicsResult.all().get()`

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that there is about a 0.1% chance of this problem occurring. 
I realize I couldn't explain the problem well. However, I could not understand how this problem could occur. I am sorry

Comment: 1) broker file deletion, or metadata removal from Zookeeper isn't immediate. 2) There's an open Kafka jira regrading this exact issue. Why use old Confluent version?

Comment: Can you send the link of the issue? From which version was this problem solved? If there is a known problem, I can upgrade to the version of Kafka you mentioned.

Comment: Not sure if it has been fixed, but [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8064) is one about a flaky test around recreation, but in general, Kafka 3.x / Confluent 7.x releases are suggested and within current Confluent Support timeframes

Comment: Also this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15619